# We know where each other stand or stands?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is "each other" singular or plural?

As in

> We know where each other stand.

or

> We know where each other stands.

I think the first is correct, as "each other" is two people collectively.

It means:

> We know where we stand respectively.

What do you think?

Comment: I stand, you stand, we stand, he stands, she stands, they stand.

Comment: It is the same as "where each of us stands" or alternatively "where we each stand". "Each" can require singular or plural, depending on the syntax, but I would prefer "each other stands", if each and other are both used.

Comment: The second one is what this American English speaker has said and heard all his life. I would judge the first one to be wrong.

Comment: I agree - if forced to use this construction, AusE would be "each other stands" as well.

Answer (score 1):

Even if "each other" represented two people collectively, that is no indication that the structure is plural.   Actual collective nouns (team, mob, group, party, &c.) are generally singular.

The phrase "each other" does not represent people collectively.   It represents them *alternately*.   It represents considering each person in the group (other than oneself) separately and in turn.   If we each know where the other stands, then you know where I stand and *in turn* I know where you stand.  We both know where each other singular person stands.

The two words in the phrase are "each" and "other".

"Each" is an adjective, or more specifically a determiner.   It fulfills the same function that articles can fill, as in "an other" or "the other".   As an adjective, it modifies singular nouns.   For example, "each man" is grammatical but "each men" is incorrect.

"Other" is a noun.   Specifically, it is the singular form of the noun.   The plural form is "others".

It is true that "where we stand respectively" is a reasonable paraphrase of "where each other stands".   However, "we" is clearly plural.   The adverb "respectively" has no direct influence over the pronoun "we" and its agreement with the governing verb.   That the two clauses have practically identical semantic values in no way reflects on the grammatical differences found between the two clauses.

The combination of a singular adjective and a singular noun remains singular.   The subject "each other" agrees with the verb "stands".

Answer (score 0):

"Each" is singular, as in "each one". We would say "each one of us stands", so therefore "each of us stands". Where does each one stand? Where does each of us stand? We know where each stands. We know where each one stands. We all take a stand, and we know where each other person stands—where each other stands.

Comment: This sounds like one of those riddles where o be tells the truth and one lies, if you know where they stand you can pass through this gate